# vuejs How to retrieve the value from elements generated in loop

Tags: loops, vue.js, datatable

So, I'm generating a table containing a checkbox and a textfield from an array of items, like a "questionnaire" where the questions come from a database.

Now, how do I, in good vue manner, retrieve if the checkboxes are checked and any text potentially input to the textfields?

I noticed that by putting "ref" on the textfields/checkboxes they become an array of vue components that are iteratable in javascript. But I haven't yet figured out how to retrieve the values correctly.

I mean, there's always the good old "get element by id" in javascript but it feels like there should be a fancier way..more "vue"-ish...

```
<table ref="questionnaire">
        <tr
          :id="item.questionId"
          row
          wrap
          v-for="(item, index) in questions"
          :key="item.questionId"
          :ref="'row_' + item.questionId"
        >
          <td>
            <label>{{item.name}}</label>
          </td>
          <td>    
            <v-checkbox ref="cbQ" value="value"></v-checkbox>
          </td>
          <td>
            <v-text-field label="Answer" ref="tbQ"></v-text-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: you can create function that pass checkbox id,question id and input value

Comment: What is the expected output? An array of all selected checkboxes with their respective values/text OR everything in the individual `question` item?

Comment: @YomS. I want to create an array of objects in javascript based on the values of the checkboxes/textfields: Like an array containgin each answer like so: var answer = {
          QuestionId: row.getAttribute("questionid"),
          Answered: cb.getAttribute("aria-checked"),
          Answer: tb.value
        };

Comment: @TobyFieldgroove Davide's answer below should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could "prepare" server side your array of questions for accepting a checked value and a text answer and then bind every checkbox and text-field to their questions with v-model like:

```
<table ref="questionnaire">
    <tr
          :id="item.questionId"
          row
          wrap
          v-for="(item, index) in questions"
          :key="item.questionId"
          :ref="'row_' + item.questionId"
    >
        <td>
            <label>{{item.name}}</label>
        </td>
        <td>    
            <v-checkbox ref="cbQ" v-model="item.checked"></v-checkbox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <v-text-field label="Answer" ref="tbQ" v-model="item.answer"></v-text-field>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But before that you should map checked and answer attributes on your questions so the v-model has already the said attributes to bind on.

At the end you will end up with an array of questions with the answers binded inside each of them.

Comment: The source of questions may change dynamically, I have no control over it so the number of questions may change at any time. I don't quite understand if your proposed solution supports this scenario? Unless I misunderstand this solution requires me to know the number of questions...=

Comment: It does! You don't have to know the number of questions to iterate over it. You just need to add the attributes previously in a each/foreach loop (or whatever you want server side) so vue doesn't freak out binding v-model to undefined props.